# Google search rankings hijacked by com.cutestat.com

Tags: hijacked

hopefully somebody can help with this query I have a domain name and if I do a Google search for "maine valley properties" one of the top results is this domain `cutestat.com`. Cutestat is some crappy domain ranking engine and they have effectively hijacked the name. I obviously would not want customers clicking on it. Does anybody know firstly how have they managed to do this ? I don't understand how it is possible to have .com twice in a domain name. Second question is how do I stop this domain name appearing in Google search results. I have looked at the WHOIS record for cutestat and they have a whole host of top level domains registered for example com.cutestat.com net.cutestat.com org.cutestat.com using this method it looks as if these people could effectively hijack any domain name.

Comment: It's obvious, Google thinks your site is crappier than `cutestat.com`, there are hundreds of sites like cutestat and they are not the problem. They are considered thin content and barely rank for anything, they haven't hijacked anything. Google has most likely penalised your site for one or more actions, or you just need to work on your rankings, either way there's currently there's nothing unique about this question other than the fact cutestat.com is outranking you which obviously we can't have a million questions covering every time someone's site is being out ranked by someone else.

Comment: These type of sites can rank fairly easily for keywords you use if and only if your site does not perform appropriately. Bone up on you SEO.